# background-size contain is not working

Tags: css

Im using jplayer and trying to stylize the play button but it is not working, here is part of the control panel codes:

html

```
                                  <li class="ui-corner-all ui-state-default jp-play"><a class="ui-icon jp-play ui-icon-play" href="javascript:;" tabindex="1" title="play">play</a></li>
                                  <li class="ui-corner-all ui-state-default jp-pause" style="display:none"><a class="ui-icon jp-pause ui-icon-pause" href="javascript:;" tabindex="1" title="pause" style="display:none">pause</a></li>
                                  <li class="ui-corner-all ui-state-default jp-stop"><a class="ui-icon jp-stop ui-icon-stop" href="javascript:;" tabindex="1" title="stop">stop</a></li>
```

for comparison, here is the style of the `li` and `a` around play button and stop button

```
li.jp-play{
    margin:0px;
    background:none;
}
a.jp-play{
    margin:0px;
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
    padding:5px;
    background:url('../../resources/images/video/play.png') no-repeat center !important;
    background-size:contain;
    background-origin:content-box;
}

li.jp-stop{
    background:none;
}

a.jp-stop{
    margin:0px;
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
    padding:5px;
    background:url('../../resources/images/video/pause.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size:contain;
    background-origin:content-box;
}
```

From the development tool, both styles have totally no difference. However I can tell that the `background-size: contain` is not working as the play button does not really shrink to the size of `a` but the stop button (or even the rest of the buttons) just work as fine. Anyone has any idea about it?

Please let me know any information you need that would help! Thanks!

Comment: Try to find a why to *demonstrate* the issue described in your problem statement. Using an embedded code snippet that can reproduce the issue will improve this question and allow for user-friendly troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `!important` on your `background` property is the problem. Since you're using the shorthand syntax for the `background` property, you're also setting *all of the browser defaults* to `!important` as well. Basically anything that you're not declaring explicitly in the shorthand.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background):

> The background CSS shorthand property assigns explicit given values and **sets missing properties to their initial values**. (emphasis mine)

Those 'initial values' include: `background-size: auto auto`. So you're basically writing:

```
background-size: auto auto !important;
background-size: contain;
```

Of course, the declaration with `!important` wins.

If you really need the `!important` declaration, put it on the specific property you're targeting (like `background-repeat` or whatever.

Here's a working example. The third uses !important.

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid #888;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
a.one {
  background:url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150') no-repeat center !important;
  background-size:contain;
  background-origin:content-box;
}
a.two {
  background:url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150') no-repeat center;
  background-size:contain;
  background-origin:content-box;
}
a.three {
  background:url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150') center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size:contain;
  background-origin:content-box;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="one"></a>
<a href="#" class="two"></a>
<a href="#" class="three"></a>
```